# Trouble connecting to open wifi networks in Arch Linux

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, laptop

I have two open WiFi networks in my building, call them A and B. I have lived here for over two years and they have always worked, but now (after being away for a while) I've been experiencing problems that I can't diagnose.

The problem is that after a while (sometimes 5 min, sometimes an hour) the network I'm connected to stops and then I have to change to the other one. And this goes on indefinitely, where I have to keep changing between networks A and B.

I'm pretty sure this is a problem with my computer, because when I connect to the same networks with my phone they work perfectly. Also I have called the IT people here and they assured me that the network is working fine. The thing is, this doesn't happen with other networks (that I've noticed).

The problem is, I don't even know how to diagnose the problem, let alone fix it. I've tried resetting these connections and restarting the computer, I've installed all the updates (because maybe it's a bug on network manager introduced by an earlier update...).

How do I go about diagnosing this problem (and subsequently solving it)?

PS: I have Arch Linux (up-to-date) on a Samsung 9 laptop.

PS2: When issuing `ping 8.8.8.8` I get normal results for a while and eventually it prints out:

```
From 000.00.000.00 icmp_seq=1311 Destination Host Unreachable
```

where the zeros above represent my current IP.

**EDIT**:

Pinging the router's IP gives me exactly the same thing as pinging `8.8.8.8`: `Destination Host Unreachable`.

This is the [output of Network Manager](https://pastebin.com/2t0yeigQ) using `journalctl --boot _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service`. Apparently the interesting line is the line with the warning and the message connection disconnected (reason 6). I have also caught a reason -3 there once or twice.

I've also tried [this suggestion here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364145) but it didn't work.

**EDIT 2**:

Adding the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:7301 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2232:1083 Silicon Motion 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Adding the output of `iwconfig` when connecting through my phone's USB:

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any                                                                                                                                         
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off                                                                                                          
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off                                                                                                               
          Power Management:off                                                                                                                                               

vpn0      no wireless extensions.                                                                                                                                            

enp0s20f0u1  no wireless extensions.                                                                                                                                         

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Adding the output of `iwconfig` when connecting through one of the WiFis while it's working (the output of the other WiFi is almost exactly the same):

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"AP A"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.785 GHz  Access Point: 24:DE:C6:D8:5E:11   
          Bit Rate=180 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The output of `iwconfig` when the WiFi isn't working is this:

```
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"AP A"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 24:DE:C6:D8:5E:01
          Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:4  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Adding the output of `lspci` just in case:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Output from `dmesg|grep -i wlp1`:

```
[13075.528210] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13075.535068] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13075.536172] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13075.592422] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                   
[13075.595240] wlp1s0: associated
[13615.742696] wlp1s0: deauthenticated from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)                                                                                    
[13616.436651] wlp1s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10
[13616.447550] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (try 1/3)
[13616.461910] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13616.464910] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (try 1/3)
[13616.467729] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                     
[13616.469656] wlp1s0: associated
[13643.275011] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 for new auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00                                                                               
[13643.294441] wlp1s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00
[13643.301633] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13643.313799] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13643.314546] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13643.374560] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                   
[13643.376725] wlp1s0: associated
[13645.942816] wlp1s0: deauthenticated from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)                                                                                    
[13647.663157] wlp1s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10
[13647.676612] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (try 1/3)
[13647.690727] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13647.694544] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (try 1/3)
[13647.698082] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                     
[13647.700552] wlp1s0: associated
[13668.363354] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP 24:de:c6:d8:5e:10 for new auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00                                                                               
[13668.380676] wlp1s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00
[13668.391924] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13668.404645] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13668.407694] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (try 1/3)
[13668.466700] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                   
[13668.470190] wlp1s0: associated
[13749.720151] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:00 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)                                                                   
[13749.747718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[13749.777939] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[13752.236392] wlp1s0: authenticate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:01
[13752.245562] wlp1s0: send auth to 24:de:c6:d8:5e:01 (try 1/3)
[13752.249108] wlp1s0: authenticated
[13752.250272] wlp1s0: associate with 24:de:c6:d8:5e:01 (try 1/3)
[13752.254149] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 24:de:c6:d8:5e:01 (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=1)                                                                                     
[13752.256603] wlp1s0: associated
[13752.258164] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
```

**EDIT 3**

I just checked the output of `iwconfig` when the connection is down and apparently the only thing that changed was the frequency from 5 to 2.4 GHz. However, I have issued the same command while the network was working and with the output being 2.4 GHz as well. So I don't think that is the reason.

Comment: That notebook model is known to have loads of wifi problems. You also do not specify neither brand of the wifi nor the model, however, it looks like a realtek which is a messed up chip. On top of all these circunstances, you also probably are bound to have wifi interferences, and probably the infra-structure is overloaded. I pretty much have honest doubts that dealing and debugging  the sum of all those situations is on-topic here. tip: add to the question the output of 
 `lsusb` and `iwconfig`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I wasn't really aware of the problems of NP900. But this laptop has worked well since I've bought it almost 2 years ago. So it would be weird that a factory hardware problem is just acting up now out of the blue. I added the outputs that you asked plus `lspci` and I see no Realtek there anywhere. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please add also an iwconfig when associated/connected to an AP, or ideally two iwconfig with the two different APs

Comment: (adding iwconfig when in both APs might be useful to see the signal strength)

Comment: What happens if you use wpa_supplicant and dhcpcd instead?

Comment: @Werdck pardon my ignorance, but I don't understand the question. The networks are open and using `wpa_supplicant` is a password-protected network, right?

Comment: The iwconfig output is....pretty interesting. Are you also able to do the same using "AP_B"?

Comment: Are those iwconfig in the same or different APs? (have you edited the AP name?)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have edited the AP name for privacy reasons, yes. And `AP B` show pretty much the same thing, although both outputs above are the same AP. Why is it interesting though?

Comment: Aruba APs, they are fairly good and robust, there goes my suspicion of bad APs. The signals seem on the low side for the 5GHz compared tp 2.4GHz, which is pretty much the norm as 5GHz is not so efficient crossing walls. 5GHz is bound to fall at some point, especially if you start moving around home, I suspect. Furthermore, you seem to have a new version of the machine which has Intel and not realtek wifi cards, lucky you. The signals seem to be pretty good, especially on the 2.4G range. You might experiment forcing the card to be 2.4GHz. A strange point is Power Management being off.

Comment: The 2.4GHz band also has errors....crowded as usual. So 5Ghz a bit on the low side, 2.4GHz crowded...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for the feedback but I'm not sure I understand the diagnosis. Basically there's no obvious reason for it? I looked up already how to force the WiFI to be 2.4 or 5 GHz but couldn't come up with something reliable. Any tips? (by the way, maybe I should mention that the frequency of this problem happening has significantly decreased in the last couple of days. I have no idea why.)

Comment: Yeah, from the Linux side there are often no obvious reasons for it. The dynamics of the WiFi workings are complex, the 2.4GHz is overused and 5GHz was selected as a shorter distance protocol to try to work around that.

Comment: It also is muddles the water when some commercial ISP routers select "randomly" which frequency they are to use based on what they think is more free. It is near impossible to do a consistent field survey in any big city in an apartment. Then all the tiny devices you carry around are transmitters. Tonight my wifi in the bedroom was a mess, start surverying things and 6-7 neighbours shifted on top of my frequency. It is a matter of time I will need an AP both in my living room and my bedroom...again, not my FreeBSD or Mac problem.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro What I can't understand also is why this problem started acting up now. I have never had any WiFi problems. I'm thinking of waiting for kernel 5 release and if that doesn't solve it, re-install Arch from scratch. Any suggestions?

Comment: None, and I honestly doubt, reinstalling whatever version will fix Wifi limitations.  Is putting more APs in the building out of question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88809/discussion-between-tomcho-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would look for are error-messages, in the kernel ring buffer, with [dmesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html). I would look for debug output of the WiFi hardware driver stack. I usually see Intel drivers reporting *associated* and *dissociated* events including reasons.

*Destination Host Unreachable* most often means there is no route to this destination. You can check routes with `ip r`. Also your ip addresses might be of interest: `ip a`. [Manual pages for ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html).

Get some more information and report back!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. [Here's a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ErdNmhBx) of the output of `dmesg|grep -i wlp1`. Pardon my ignorance, but is this the keyword I should be looking for? Looking for `wlan0` shows me nothing.

Comment: The keyword for your `grep` looks good and I can't find anything suspicious there. If you are using Network Manager you could look into its logs with this command `journalctl --boot _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service`.

Comment: Also try to ping your router (in `ip r` the IP address after *via*) while your connection  (ping to `8.8.8.8`) is not working.

Comment: Pinging the router just gives me exactly the same thing as pinging `8.8.8.8`: `Destination Host Unreachable`. This is the [output of Network Manager](https://pastebin.com/2t0yeigQ). Apparently the interesting line is the line with the warning and the message `connection disconnected (reason 6)`. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465848/frequent-deauthentication-from-wifi-reason-6-in-a-centrino-advanced-n-6230-r) with a similar error which I will investigate.

Comment: "reason 6: class2FrameFromNonAuthStation: Client attempted to transfer data before it was authenticated." (from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/#Logbucheintraege-auswerten). From your log it looks like your where successfully authenticated and assosiated.
Also you got reason 3 in your dmesg log, which states the access point is going offline. Maybe someone is running *death attack* in your neighborhood: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_deauthentication_attack .
You could try to use the Wireshark packet sniffer to see if it's an deauth attack.

Comment: I see what you mean. But wouldn't a death attack mean I can't connect using my phone too? Because my phone connects fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88520/discussion-between-thomas-and-tomcho).

Comment: Please amend question, amenda in comments may not be noticed, and stuff on another site makes it hard to see.